# Excel Error "Sorry, we couldn't find 'XXX' Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?"

Tags: microsoft-excel

Getting this error in excel when I open a file. When I search I can't find where this reference is in my excel file.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to Edit Links

[image]

You might have more enteries, select the one where status us unknown and `Break Link` button. You can also press `Check Status` and it will give you the same message box.

[image]

But where is the cell where I have this reference? I don't think I have a reference, it seems to be a bug perhaps.

You can search for `[*]` or `*[*]` because all references in Excel are in square brackets. This may return a large number so you can narrow down search like `*[*]*test*` where `test` is the file name.

In my case nothing showed up (as expected so I just break the link) and that fixed the problem.

[image]